# Как это вывести с помощью smarty?

Tags: php, переменные, smarty

#### В общем, есть код:

**servers** - выводит список серверов.
**groups** - список товаров.
Как сделать так, чтобы при смене сервера менялись и товары которые находятся в select?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public function servers() {
    return $this->query("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `status` = 1");
}

public function groups($server) {
    $groups = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `server` = ".(int)$server." ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    $donate = array();
    while($group = $groups->fetch_object()) {
        if(!is_array($donate[$group->category])) $donate[$group->category] = array();
        $donate[$group->category][] = $group;
    }
    return $donate;
}
```

В шаблонизаторе вот так (smarty версии 3):

```
$smarty->assign('servers', $core->servers());
$smarty->assign('groups', $core->groups($server['id']));
```

html:

```
                <div class="col-md-6">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    {foreach from=$servers item=$server}
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a href="#tab{$server.id}" {if $server.id==1} class="nav-link active" {/if} class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{$server.name}</a></li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
                <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px;border-top-right-radius: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            {foreach from=$servers item=$server}
                            <div role="tabpanel" {if $server.id==1} class="tab-pane active" {/if} class="tab-pane" id="tab{$server.id}">
                                <form action="/" method="post" id="forma"><input type="hidden" name="server_id" class="input-server_id" value="{$server.id}">
                                    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning">
                                        Вы выбрали сервер: {$server.name}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                        <label for="nick" class="control-label">Введите ваш ник:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="input-nick form-control" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Введите ник">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="group" class="control-label">Выберите товар:</label>
                                        <select id="group" name="group" class="form-control" required="">
                                            <option selected disabled>Выберите товар</option>
                                            {foreach from=$groups item=$list key=$category}
                                            <optgroup label="{$category}">
                                                {foreach from=$list item=$group}
                                                <option value="{$group->id}">{$group->name} - {$group->price} руб.</option>
                                                {/foreach}
                                            </optgroup>
                                            {/foreach}
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" name="buy" id="buy" class="submit buy btn btn-info" disabled="">Купить</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: вы хоть покажите, что там у вас в `groups` находится этом. и версию смарти, 2 или 3

Comment: Отредактировал, посмотрите.

Comment: перестраивайте селект на стороне клиента при смене сервера. Либо у вас будут вкладки на которых разные селекты для каждого сервера.

Comment: Я понимаю что я уже где-то близок, но не знаю как правильно перестроить.

Comment: Я так и не понял как это сделать

Comment: обратите внимание, как у вас классы в ифах прописываются `{if ..]class="active"{/if} class="tab"` в некоторых случаях приводитк тому, что у вас два атрибута `class`. Пишите внутри `class="tab {if ..}active{/if}"`

Comment: а так вам надо извлечь все группы сразу,  вне зависимости от сервера. и сгруппировать их  в массив, где ключом будет id сервера. PDO такое позволяет делать из коробки (не знаю, что там у вас используется). А то вы хотите вывести для всех серверов, а по итогу данные выбираете только для одного

Answer (score 0):

на стороне пхп вы вбираете данные и передаете их в шаблонизатор, а-ля

```
 $groups = $this->groups($server['id']);
 $smarty->assign('groups', $groups);

 $smarty->render(...);
```

в шаблоне юзаете, что передали. Если смарти 3й версии, то

```
 {foreach $groups as $category => $list}
 <optgroup label="{$category}">
      {foreach $list as $group}
      <options value="{$group.id}">{$group.name} - {$group.price} руб.</option>
      {/foreach}
 </optgroup>
 {/foreach}
```